# The application, MyEAR, is trying to modify a cookie which matches a pattern in the restricted programmatic session cookies list

Tags: cookies, websphere, jsessionid

I am getting below exception while deploying my application on WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5

java.lang.RuntimeException: SRVE8111E: The application, MyEAR, is trying to modify a cookie which matches a pattern in the restricted programmatic session cookies list [domain=*, name=JSESSIONID, path=/].

I found that if I remove below entry from my web.xml [session-config], then no error is shown with deployment and every things works fine.

```
<cookie-config> 
<http-only>true</http-only> 
</cookie-config> 
<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
```

The same ear is able to deploy and run perfectly with JBOSS and WebLogic server.

Please let me know what configuration change I have to do in which xml file to overcome this issue.

My application has application.xml, jboss-deployment-structure.xml and weblogic-application.xml.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the server to allow you to modify the session cookie it's using for HTTP Sessions, you can remove the cookie from Security > Global security > Programmatic session cookie configuration. in the WAS Admin Console.

But you shouldn't modify the session cookie.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Websphere App Server and this was fixed after I changed the cookie path to the context root instead of the path =/. You could try the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, removing them from Global security is a solution, but this will impact other application also.

How I fixed this.

Changed the name of sessionId from default jsessionid to something else.